# Does any one know some tool to create multiple Google Accounts in batch mode?

Tags: google-app-engine

Do you know some tool that allow me to create several google accounts in batch mode?
I have Google for Education in my company and I will have to create 100 users account in order to allow them to use my Google Apps applications and forms.

I was wondering if there is a way to create these accounts programmatically or some tool could do that.

Any tip I will be happy to hear!!

Cheers,
Fernando﻿

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) allows you to create users programmatically.

You'll need either domain-wide authorization of a service account (established via a Google Console API project) or OAuth2 creds from an admin user in order to successfully make the API calls.